# Easyrec signup after installation- Account is not getting created

Tags: recommendation-engine

[image: Easyrec Signup page]

Account is not getting created and the UI stays in the signup page. Not able to makeout the possible reason. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the issue.
It was a Maven project and I was deploying it without maven install and tomcat:run.

The project was run from eclipse due to this the dependency projects were not included causing the issue.

Thanks anyways.